# How do load the angularJS module into an application?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-services, dependencies

I am receiving the following error:

> Unhandled exception at line 24, column 180 in
>   https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js
>
> 0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: [$injector:nomod]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$injector/nomod?p0=undefined,

I have my scripts loaded within the page and am not referencing any JavaScript files except for the app.js and module for controllers within the project like below:

```
  <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/someApp.js"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/someModule.js"></script>
        <title>Box labeling Program</title>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="someApp">
<div ng-controller="someCtrl">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The angularJS that I thinking I need below (someApp.js):

```
angular.module('someApp'['someModule'])
.config([function () {
    console.log("Config hook")
}])
.run([function () {
    console.log("Run the hook");
}])
```

There seems to be an issue with angular.min.js, it does not seem to know what object it needs from the reference. I have changed the placement of the script to below the body tag, though this does not seem to change anything.

Also, here is the what I suspect that I need to use for the creating controllers,

```
angular.module('someModule', [])
.config([function () {
    console.log("Some Module:: config");
}])
.run([function () {
        console.log("Some Module:: running");
}])

.controller('SomeCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.theName ="Julie"
}])
}])
```

Comment: change the loading order so modules that are dependency injected load before they are called on

Comment: Are you referring to the modules in the javascript file?

Comment: referring to angular modules yes. Your app file loads with a dependency that is being loaded after it

Comment: Also can use the full development version of angular for more verbose error and stack trace output. The minified version only provides links to docs site with errors

Comment: I changed the ordering of the scripts to something like,
 <script src="Scripts/mainApp.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/mainModule.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
and that seem to fix the error, though now I get a:

Unhandled exception at line 1, column 1 in http://localhost:60391/Scripts/mainApp.js

0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'angular' is undefined

Is there the possibility that I am missing another dependency?

Comment: is angular loading before app.js?

Comment: the angular library always has to be loaded first. The order is Angular > Dependencies > Main App.js

Comment: I changed the ordering and it works now, though why does the ordering matter?

Answer (score 1):

If this is your actual code then you are missing a comma between 'someApp' and the injected dependency ['someModule']. Although angular gives pretty generic error messages you can infer something to this point by the fact that it is a runtime error. That suggests an error in code not in logic. it also states: [$injector:nomod]. Which means there is no module to inject.

If this is just an approximation of your code and not the actual code then we really can't help you. I only say this because what you've provided is exceptionally generic and is either an exercise you're performing or your attempt to hide code for some reason. If that's the case then our ability to help is limited.

Comment: This code is just example of code that am attempting to use. I have ran to this problem once before. Though unsure how to solve it, there really is not much changed from the code that am trying to apply this to.

Comment: So, did you make sure your module name and the dependencies are separated by a comma? Because they aren't in this code snippet

Comment: Yes, here is what I changed it to:
angular.module('mainApp', ['mainModule'])
.config([function () {
    console.log("Config hook")
}])
.run([function () {
    console.log("Run the hook");
}])

Comment: Though now am getting 403.14 error page when I run the app.

Comment: Well a 403 is a forbidden error code. Specifically meaning your directory listing is denied. Whatever your problem is we won't be able to help unless you actually give the code and its context.